# Issue with giving a title to a menu

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to give a text name for this menu but it won't let me saying there's an Extra argument in call what's wrong ? PS: I'm a beginner in coding

```
        Divider()
      
   
            Menu("\(buttonTitle)" ) {
            Button("Riyadh",action: {SelectRiyadh()})
            Button("Dammam",action: {SelectDammam()})
            Button("Jeddah",action: {SelectJeddah()})
            Button("Mecca",action: {SelectMecca()})
        
        }
```

Comment: Please check this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-a-menu-when-a-button-is-pressed

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the ContentView page, but try to wrap all that code in some group or into stack, for example VStack.

Anyway, read this article first: [How to show a menu when a button is pressed](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-a-menu-when-a-button-is-pressed)

```
VStack{
             Divider()
             Menu("\(buttonTitle)" ) {
             Button("Riyadh",action: {option()})
      }
}
```